# Insert into by chunks

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use `insert into` statement, but getting the error:

> ORA-01628: max # extents (32765) reached for rollback segment _SYSSMU134_1882489978$

Increasing the `UNDO` tablespace is not an option, so I would like a way to insert those data by chunks (for example with 1 million rows at a time). Can someone help to rewrite this procedure in that way?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_chunks (
  p_source_table IN VARCHAR2,
  p_table_name_chunk IN VARCHAR2,
  p_chunks IN VARCHAR2
) AS
v_insert_sql CLOB;
BEGIN
  v_insert_sql := 'INSERT INTO ' || p_table_name_chunk ||
    ' (rid, chunk_number) ' ||
    'SELECT /*+ parallel(64) */ rowid rid,' ||
      'mod( ora_hash(rowid), :p_chunks ) as chunk_number '
    'FROM ' || p_source_table;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_insert_sql USING p_chunks;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

This `v_insert_sql` is failing with above mentioned error. I have working solution using the cursor fetching like that:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR v_cur IS SELECT /*+ parallel(64) */
    rowid rid, mod( ora_hash(rowid), 20000 ) AS chunk_number
  -- I need this table to be parametric name
  FROM some_table;
  TYPE t_sample IS TABLE OF v_cur%ROWTYPE;
  v_sample t_sample;
  v_row_limit CONSTANT NUMBER := 1000000;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur BULK COLLECT INTO v_sample LIMIT v_row_limit;
    FORALL i IN v_sample.first .. v_sample.last
      INSERT INTO chunk_table VALUES v_sample(i);
    COMMIT;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
```

I can't move this cursor straight into the procedure as the table name is varying and I need it to be parametric as with cursor approach I have to repeat the same code for different tables. So the question is how to deal with this?

Comment: So do you have a key on the `p_source_table` table which you can use to track which rows have been processed? Alternatively, how many tables do you want to pipe through this procedure? Does it really have to be completely dynamic?

Comment: @APC I don't have a key, as it will be either success or we have to retry for the whole. Yes it should be dynamic as we need to process ~70 tables.

Comment: But your whole question is predicated on being able to insert and commit chunks of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I was able to just past the whole chunks approach inside procedure as dynamic query, like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_chunks (
  p_source_table IN VARCHAR2,
  p_table_name_chunk IN VARCHAR2,
  p_chunks IN VARCHAR2
) AS
  v_insert_sql CLOB;
BEGIN
  v_insert_sql := '' ||
    ' DECLARE ' || CHR(10) ||
    ' CURSOR cur1 IS SELECT ' || CHR(10) ||
    '   /*+ parallel(64) full(tbn)*/ rowid rid,' || CHR(10) ||
    '   mod( ora_hash(rowid), :p_chunks ) AS chunk_number' || CHR(10) ||
    ' FROM ' || p_source_table || ' tbn;' || CHR(10) ||
    ' TYPE t_sample IS TABLE OF cur1%ROWTYPE;' || CHR(10) ||
    ' v_sample t_sample;' || CHR(10) ||
    ' v_row_limit CONSTANT NUMBER := 1000000;' || CHR(10) ||
    ' BEGIN' || CHR(10) ||
    '   OPEN cur1;' || CHR(10) ||
    '   LOOP' || CHR(10) ||
    '     FETCH cur1 BULK COLLECT INTO v_sample LIMIT v_row_limit;' || CHR(10) ||
    '     FORALL i IN v_sample.first .. v_sample.last' || CHR(10) ||
    '       INSERT INTO ' || p_table_name_chunk || ' VALUES v_sample(i);' || CHR(10) ||
    '     COMMIT;' || CHR(10) ||
    '     EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;' || CHR(10) ||
    '   END LOOP;' || CHR(10) ||
    '   CLOSE cur1;' || CHR(10) ||
    ' END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_insert_sql USING p_chunks;
  COMMIT;
END;
```